# Does there exist such a group?

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

First Question: I was asked, "Find a group that has a subgroup of order $n$ for each positive integer $n$. I considered the nonzero complex numbers under multiplication, and noticed that the roots of the polynomial $x^n-1$ will generate a group. Is this right?

Second Question: I asked myself, "does there exist a group $G$ that has every subgroup up to isomorphism for each positive integer $n$?" For example, if we let $n=24$, there are $15$ different groups up to isomorphism. So I want the group $G$ to have $15$ subgroups of order $24$ that none of them are pairwise isomorphic. If anyone can phrase this question better, please edit my post.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Take the direct product of every finite group. For a less artificial example, take the infinite symmetric group $S_{\infty}$ (there are two groups this could refer to and either will work).

Comment: Would you mind explaining the infinite symmetric group to me? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Just to be clear, the roots of the polynomial $x^n-1$, for a fixed $n$, form a group of order $n$. It is the union of all such roots, for all $n$, which makes a group containing a subgroup of order $n$ for each $n$.

Comment: @GentGjonbalaj I'm no group theorist, but I think $S_\infty$ refers to the group of permutations on a countably infinite set (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$). Every group of any order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$, and $S_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_\infty$.

Comment: @ziggurism : OP's group for 1 is actually $\mathbb{C}^*$

Comment: Oh right. I missed that.

Comment: For your clarified version of 2, where each subgroup occurs precisely once, the answer is no. For example, your group must contain, but cannot contain, the Klein 4-group (which contains three non-equal cyclic subgroups of order two).

Comment: Yes, Theo describes one of the possible meanings of $S_{\infty}$. The other is the subgroup of permutations on an infinite set with finite support (that is, which fix all but finitely many elements); this is equivalently the increasing union $\cup_n S_n$.